# Pandas dataframe custom forward fillna optimisation

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, pandas

### Question

Dear all,
I have a function that synchronizes according to some specifications columns of a `dataframe`.
**The functions works**, nevertheless I was wondering **how to**:

- **Improve performances**
- **Make it more pythonic**

Please feel free to leave any suggestions,
Thanks.

---

### The function, a sample and results

#### Function specifications

1. *Inputs*:

   - **`df`** : a `dataframe` with columns:

     - `[a0,...aN]` : `a0` to `aN` names can be any valid `string` and contains `numeric` values
     - `[agent,date]` : are fixed names, `agent` contains `numeric` values and `date` contains `datetime`.
   - **`sync_with`** : The columns to synchronize with (a `string` or an `listof string` contained in `[a0,..., aN]` or, by default, an `empty list` to synchronize all the `[a0,...,aN]`.
2. *Synchronization*:

   - Do a forward `fillna` grouped by agent values.
   - Drop the rows where all columns to synchronize with values are empty
3. *Returns* : the synchronized `dataframe`

Here is my function:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def synchronize(df,sync_with=[]):
    _df = df.copy()

    if not isinstance(sync_with,list):
        sync_with = [sync_with]

    _fixed_cols = ['date','agent']
    _fixed_cols.extend(sync_with)
    _colset = [c for c in _df.columns if c not in _fixed_cols]

    for ag in _df.agent.unique():
        _df.loc[_df.agent==ag,_colset] = _df.loc[_df.agent==ag,_colset].fillna(method='ffill')
        if sync_with:
            _df = _df.dropna(how='all', subset=sync_with)
            _df.loc[_df.agent==ag,:] = _df.loc[_df.agent==ag,:].fillna(method='ffill')

    return _df
```

#### Sample

```
foo = pd.DataFrame(dict(date=pd.to_datetime(['2010', '2011', '2012', '2013', '2010', '2013', '2015', '2016']),
                        agent=[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2],
                        _a=[1, np.nan, np.nan, 4, 5, np.nan, 7, 8],
                        _b=[11, 22, np.nan, np.nan, 55, np.nan, 77, np.nan],
                        _c=[111, np.nan, 333, np.nan, np.nan, 666, 777, np.nan]))
```

#### Results

```
# 1. default (10.1 ms per loop)
print(synchronize(foo))
    _a    _b     _c  agent       date
0  1.0  11.0  111.0      1 2010-01-01
1  1.0  22.0  111.0      1 2011-01-01
2  1.0  22.0  333.0      1 2012-01-01
3  4.0  22.0  333.0      1 2013-01-01
4  5.0  55.0    NaN      2 2010-01-01
5  5.0  55.0  666.0      2 2013-01-01
6  7.0  77.0  777.0      2 2015-01-01
7  8.0  77.0  777.0      2 2016-01-01

# 2. sync with one column (54.9 ms per loop)
print(synchronize(foo,'_c'))
    _a    _b     _c  agent       date
0  1.0  11.0  111.0      1 2010-01-01
2  1.0  22.0  333.0      1 2012-01-01
5  NaN   NaN  666.0      2 2013-01-01
6  7.0  77.0  777.0      2 2015-01-01

# 3. sync with two columns (53.4 ms per loop)
print(synchronize(foo,['_a','_b'))
    _a    _b     _c  agent       date
0  1.0  11.0  111.0      1 2010-01-01
1  1.0  22.0  111.0      1 2011-01-01
3  4.0  22.0  333.0      1 2013-01-01
4  5.0  55.0    NaN      2 2010-01-01
6  7.0  77.0  777.0      2 2015-01-01
7  8.0  77.0  777.0      2 2016-01-01
```